# Clone an object, skipping circular references with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clone, circular-reference

I have this code that's based off of Crockford's [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) but it's stripping out way more than it should be from the input object. For some reason it's identifying almost everything as seen already in the cache and skipping it.

I'm not entirely sure what the point of the WeakMap is as opposed to a Set, so that could be a part of the problem. I've tried interchanging the two, but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

Here's the code. I've made it self-contained enough that you should be able to just drop it in the browser console.

```js
const message = (function cloneWithoutCircularReferences(object) {
    const cache = new WeakMap();

    const clone = Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {};

    function getKeyOfObjectByPath(object, path) {
        return path.reduce(function(object, key) {
            return object[key];
        }, clone) || clone;
    }

    (function traverse(object, path = []) {
        try {
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
                if (typeof object === "object" && object !== null) {
                    if (cache.has(object)) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    cache.set(object, path);

                    getKeyOfObjectByPath(object, path)[key] = Array.isArray(object[key]) ? [] : {};

                    traverse(value, [...path, key]);
                } else {
                    getKeyOfObjectByPath[key] = value;
                }
            }
        } catch (error) { }
    })(object);

    return clone;
})(globalThis); // I'm using `globalThis` since it's an easily accessible object with circular references. The actual object I want to decircularize is an array of doubly linked objects.

console.log(message);
```

---

Here's a screenshot of the specific object I'm trying to decircularize. Notice the `next` key is a reference to the next object in the doubly linked list.

Additionally, `subject` points to the `window` object so that is also going to contain some circular references.

[image]

---

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: The obvious problem is that in a circular reference, you have no idea where the circle starts and you should start skipping things

Comment: Please post "*the actual object I want to decircularize [that] is a doubly linked list/array of objects*" and what you result you expect for it.

Comment: @Bergi Done, to the best that I can.

Comment: I meant, can you please post the code that constructs an object of the structure you have problems with, and the desired output as JSON? I can't really tell what is special about that `next` property you want to have omitted

Comment: I've determined that what I actually need is a BFS-based clone function with a cache to weed out seen elements. DFS won't help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a breadth-first search, with a Set to cache the seen values, and added the ability to blacklist keys and limit traversal depth.

I wasn't thrilled about having to add those options, but the children were just unique enough that they were getting past the cache.

```
(function cloneWithoutCircularReferences(object, options) {
    const cache = new Set([window]);

    function getKeyOfObjectByPath(object, path) {
        return path.reduce(function(object, key) {
            return object[key];
        }, clone) || clone;
    }

    const clone = Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {};

    for (const queue = [{ "path": [], "node": object }]; queue.length !== 0;) {
        const { path, node } = queue.shift();

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(node)) {
            if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
                if (cache.has(value) || options.blacklistedKeys.includes(key) || path.length >= options.maxLength) {
                    continue;
                }

                cache.add(value);

                queue.push({
                    "path": [...path, key],
                    "node": value
                });

                getKeyOfObjectByPath(clone, path)[key] = Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {};
            } else {
                try {
                    getKeyOfObjectByPath(clone, path)[key] = value;
                } catch (error) { }
            }
        }
    }

    return clone;
})(message, options);
```